# Python Pandas populate column from partial string match

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe like below, and I need to create a new column `Block` with either the value `1` or `2` in it based on a partial string match in the column `Program Number` where it says _block_1 or _block_2. I've been trying if statements and `.str.contains` but can't get it to work. How would you do this?

```
148 0209-3SP_block_1    ['g76p010060q00250r.0005'   'JEBD0507160 REV A' CHNCIII
149 0209-3SP_block_2    ['g76x.3761z-.500p03067q03067f.05'  'JEBD0507160 REV A' CHNC III
150 0209-5SP_block_1    ['g76p020060q00250r.0005'   'JEBD0507160 REV A' CHNC III
151 0209-5SP_block_2    ['g76x.3767z-.48p03067q03067f.05'   'JEBD0507160 REV A' CHNC III
152 0210-3SP_block_1    ['g76p010060q00250r.0005'   'JEBD0507160 REV A' CHNC III
```

Comment: Just tried another method:
`block1 = df['Machine'].str.contains('_block_1')

df['Block'] = block1.replace((True,False), ('1','2'))`

but this added all `2` to column

Comment: See [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html), specifically regex part.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's actually what I've been using on this last attempt, the section Testing for Strings that Match or Contain a Pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the method `where` from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Block'] = np.where(
    df['Machine'].str.contains('_block_1'),1,
    np.where(df['Machine'].str.contains('_block_2'),2,0)
)
```

Otherwise, assuming all the strings have the same length:

```
df['Block'] = df['Machine'].str[15:].astype(int)
```